# Pending Transaction from locked token

Tags: ether, myetherwallet, etherscan, pending-transactions, etherdelta

I tried to send locked EOS to Etherdelta, and the transaction been pending for almost 4 days now.

MEW can't find the transaction so I'm unable to cancel it nor do anything else even with higher gas price.

sometimes the transaction disappears from etherscan but then start again after few minutes.

here is that [bad boy](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x2a071c5e82489b8b26abd71c31fa720a494b4a0cadd2e79b8a7df3b547081b76)

If there's anyone that can assist, I will be forever grateful

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to resend the exact same transaction (same data, same nonce [530], ...) with higher gas price and overwrite/cancel the existing one.

According to [EthGasStation](https://ethgasstation.info), the current average gas price is **80 gwei** (I know it's high!!!) and it should confirm a transaction in 30 seconds max.

[EthGasStation Transaction GasPrice/Confirmation time Calculator](https://ethgasstation.info/calculatorTxV.php)

- Gas Limit: 250000
- Gas Price: 80gwei

> % of last 200 blocks accepting this gas price     90.1041666667
>
> Transactions At or Above in Current Txpool    155
>
> Mean Time to Confirm (Blocks)     2
>
> Mean Time to Confirm (Seconds) 31
>
> Transaction fee (ETH) 0.02
>
> Transaction fee (Fiat)    $9.2